# Laravel build multi-lang route system

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, multilingual

im using Laravel 5, and i have this route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}/', 'middleware' => 'SetLanguage'], function($lang){
//element Show
    Route::get('/'.trans('routes.element-container').'/{slugName}', 'ElementController@showByName');
});
```

My middleware is this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (in_array($request->lang, config('app.all_langs'))){
        //exit("SETTING ON ".$request->lang);
        App::setLocale($request->lang);
    }else{
        //exit("SETTING ON en");
        App::setLocale('en');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

If i un-comment the two exit it works, but, the function "trans" on route side is not working, seems to trans only in default lang.

why the "trans" function is called before the middleware?
I have test with 'before' and 'after', but no work...

Comment: Why don't you just get the language from the route in ElementController@showByName and translate it there instead of translating on the route declaration?

Comment: because is multi-lang route, ex:

http://www.example.com/en/element-container/element-a

http://www.example.com/de/Elemente-Behälter/element-a

Comment: I see your problem now. The function `trans()` will always be called before the middleware, so one option I can think of is to declare the same route as much times as languages you have or to have a controller method which will receive the language, translate the route and redirect to correct named route depending on that language.

Comment: Also you could use the `$lang` variable to get the route name from a config with the language routes or some array. Like `["routes.element-container.{$lang}"]`.

Comment: I had thought the same thing and i have tested with:
    App::setLocale($lang);  After route group, but seems not work

Comment: And if i set manually like App::setLocale('en') it works -.- ahah

Comment: I get.. Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Router could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could consider something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}/', 'middleware' => 'SetLanguage'], function() {
    foreach (config('app.all_langs') as $language) {
        $translatedRoute = trans('routes.element-container', [], $language);
        Route::get("/$translatedRoute/{slugName}", 'ElementController@showByName');
    }
});
```

But this will also register routes for e.g. `/de/element-container/element-a`.

Alternative:

```
foreach (config('app.all_langs') as $language) {
    Route::group(['prefix' => $language, 'middleware' => 'SetLanguage'], function() {
        $translatedRoute = trans('routes.element-container', [], $language);
        Route::get("/$translatedRoute/{slugName}", 'ElementController@showByName');
    });
}
```

This will register `/en/element-container/element-a` and `/de/Elemente-Behälter/element-a`, but not `/de/element-container/element-a`

Comment: Solved, but now not passing "lang" variable to controller and i had to get it manually from controller, using "Request::segment(1)": bad method.. :(

Here my route:
foreach (config('app.all_langs') as $lang) {
    App::setLocale($lang);

    Route::group(['prefix' => $lang/*, 'middleware' => 'SetLanguage'*/], function() {
        $translatedRoute = trans('routes.element-directory');
        Route::get("/".$translatedRoute."/{slugName}", ['uses' => 'ElementController@showByName']);
    });

}